# rateit plugin not showing all 5 stars

Tags: jquery-plugins

I've been using the excellent jQuery RateIt plug-in (https://rateit.codeplex.com) for some functionality on my website.

You can view the issue in the plunkr below:
http://plnkr.co/edit/P4vHp1qP1HSiLfOkk69E?p=preview

The problem I'm having is that whilst the big stars show up fine, the little ones skip every other star.

I have *tweaked* the CSS a little (rateit.mine.css) as I have a separate sprite file I use.  I'm 99% sure it's something *I'm* doing wrong rather than the plug-in, but I just can't see what *I'm* doing wrong :(

Many thanks in advance for any insight anyone can offer.

Regards,
Franz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was being silly and breaking the *thinking about performance before I need to rule*.

I'd merged the big and little star sprites into one PNG file so there was only the one request for the sprite.  Ordinarily this would be fine, however ...

The small stars are 16px wide, but because the big stars are 32px wide there was 16px of whitespace to the left of the little stars.

So the 2nd and 4th stars that were *missing* were in fact the whitespace in the PNG.

The words ooops and Doh! spring to mind :)